# Text in TextView fades out when scrolling

Tags: java, android, textview

I'm using a text view to show some in-app logging statements.  The old code I had placed a text view inside of a scroll view, but I was having some memory issues so I removed the scroll view. I set up the text view like this:

```
this.setText(text);
this.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

This allows me to scroll through the text, but the text fades out when scrolling. It's white text on a black background and it fades out to a very dark grey. Once I release my finger the text color comes back, but I would prefer for it to not fade out at all.  I also get a LogCat statement of:

```
TextView does not support text selection. Action mode cancelled.
```

Not sure if that is related, I don't want the text to be editable, but I feel as if the fading may be the app telling me I can't edit the text.

Edit: I set `setTextIsSelectable` to true, and now it does not fade when scrolling, but it lets the user select text which is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it, the solution was to hard code the text color:

```
this.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

I'm sure there is some other setting I could have disabled but I couldn't find it, and this worked.  If someone can give a more in depth solution with some option to disable fading, I will gladly accept that answer over this one.